# Unable to display received data

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular-services

Hi I am new to angular and spring. I am trying to create a small example where i receive a user data from server and display it on webpage. I have successfully established connection but I am unable to print received data. Attached is the code.

Webpage code:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in data">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </div>

    <script>
        var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
        app.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope,$http){
            $scope.data=[];
            $http.get("/loginUser").then(function(response){
                $scope.data=response
            },function(){

            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(value="/loginUser",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getLoginInfo(){
    String loginInfo="Controller hit";
    System.out.println(loginInfo);
    List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(new User("Jayant"));
    System.out.println(users.size());
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}
```

User Class:

```
public class User {

private String name;

public User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: are you recieving the data?

Comment: I am having simliar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $http.get("/loginUser").then(function(response){
            $scope.data=response.data;
```

Instead of response use response.data